# How to query S3 public dataset using redshift

Tags: mysql, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Amazon AWS documentation is just awful and totally unhelpful. Feels good to get that out now we can get down to the actual issue.

I am using SQL workbench to connect to my redshift cluster I am able to connect fine but can't run any commands...

How can I query the common crawl s3 dataset?

Comment: to query the result you first need to load it in to the redshift. Take a look at "copy" command

Comment: I tried that and all I get is syntax errors. How am I supposed to know the table names of a public dataset?

Answer (score 0):

The [Common Crawl Corpus](https://aws.amazon.com/datasets/41740) dataset provided in Amazon S3 is [apparently formatted as WARC files](http://blog.commoncrawl.org/2013/11/new-crawl-data-available/). However, Amazon Redshift can only load CSV files (uncompressed, GZIP or LZOP).

Therefore, you will need to pre-process the Common Crawl files into an appropriate format for loading into Amazon Redshift. One way of doing this would be to use Amazon Elastic MapReduce (EMR). The page says:

> Common Crawl provides the glue code required to launch Hadoop jobs on Amazon Elastic MapReduce that can run against the crawl corpus residing here in the Amazon Public Data Sets.

Please note that this would be a rather complex process (as is anything involving Hadoop).